# Strange error message when a class method is missing

Tags: c++, oop, ld

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GCC C++ Linker errors: Undefined reference to 'vtable for XXX', Undefined reference to 'ClassName::ClassName()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095298/gcc-c-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-xxx-undefined-referen)

I have been banging my head against a wall for a long time because of a strange ld error.
So I reproduced it in a small test case to understand the issue.

I declared a class and I derived another one in a header file:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
  BaseClass(){};
  virtual void func(){};
};

class DerivedClass: public BaseClass {
public:
  DerivedClass();
  void func();
};
```

Then I defined the constructor but forgot to define `func` (voluntary here, but that actually what I did with a silly copy/paste...):

```
DerivedClass::DerivedClass(){
  cout << "Derived constructor" << endl;
}

//void DerivedClass::func(){
//  cout << "Derived func" << endl;
//}
```

Then I get:

> undefined reference to `vtable for DerivedClass'

Edit: And the message points the declaration of the consctructor!

If I uncomment the definition of `func`, then I have no error. So my question:
Why does the linker didn't tell me that the definition of `func` is missing?

The solution might be obvious when you are experienced, but for a  beginner like me it's not!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095298/gcc-c-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-xxx-undefined-referen and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334269/undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-classname and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511973/undefined-reference-to-vtable any many others. Also, the question is answered in the GCC FAQ. http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables

Comment: @RaymondChen: Even if a little bit rude, your answer with the link to GCC FAQ helped understanding the issue. I +1ed you!

Comment: @ChristianRau: GCC in Eclipse!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vtable` is created for the class that contains virtual function and for the classes derived from it.It means in your program `vtable` will be created for `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass`.Each of these `vtables` would contain the address of virtual function `void func()`.Now note that `DerivedClass`  doesn't contain the definition of `void func()`,hence its `vtable` contains the address of `BaseClass`'s `void func()` function.That's why the compiler is giving error `undefined reference to vtable for DerivedClass`.

Comment: If I well understood the [GCC FAQ](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables) that Raymond Chen gave above, I think you're almost right. What I didn't understood is the fact that the linker failed on the class constructor (but I forgot to mention this here...). And linking would have fail at the definition of the first method among constructor and destructor (maybe other but I am not sure).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your compiler didn't generate a `vtable` for the `DerivedClass`. A `vtable` is basically a table that contains function pointers for every virtual function. By storing a pointer to the class's `vtable` (usually called `vptr`) for every object the correct virtual function to call can be determined at runtime. Although it is an implementation detail of the specific compiler, this is the usual way to implement virtual functions, which are bound at runtime and can therefore not be called like normal functions.

My first guess would be that the compiler didn't generate a `vtable` for `DerivedClass` because it doesn't define any virtual functions so it uses the `BaseClass`'s `vtable`. Although that's a bit strange, it is the only idea I can come up with. But I'm not that well-versed in compiler architecture and maybe somebody has a better solution.

Comment: Basically the answer is it's not handled by ld! Anyway, thank you for your explanation.